# Integral over a ball.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Let for $0<t<t_0$
>   $$e(t)=\int_{B(x, R(t_0-t))}v(x,t)dx$$
>   Given that $v(x,t)$ is a differentiable function prove that 
>   $$e'(t)=\int_{B(x, R(t_0-t))}v_t-R\int_{\partial B(x, R(t_0-t))}vdS$$

I know that I have to do some change of variable. But I don't see which. Somebody can give a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generalisation of [Leibniz's rule for differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule),
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(x,t) \, dx = b'(t) f(b(t),t)-a'(t) f(a(t),t) + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \, dx  $$

You can do yours by considering

$$ e(t+h)-e(t) = \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t-h))} v(y,t+h) \, dy - \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t))} v(y,t) \, dy \\
= \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t-h))} v(y,t+h) \, dy - \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t-h))} v(y,t) \, dy + \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t-h))} v(y,t) \, dy  - \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t))} v(y,t) \, dy $$

Mean value theorem on the integrand in the first term gives
$$ \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t-h))} v(y,t+h) \, dy - \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t-h))} v(y,t) \, dy = h \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t-h))} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(y,\tau) \, dy + o(h), $$
and of the second, using the mean value theorem gives
$$ \int_{B(x,R(t_0-t-h)) \setminus B(x,R(t_0-t)} v(y,t) \, dy = -Rh \int_{\partial B(x,R(t_0-\tau')} v(y,\tau') \, dy, $$
where both of $\tau,\tau'$ satisfy $t<\tau,\tau'<h$. Now divide by $h$ and take the limit as $h \to 0$.